# Design a pattern using python

Tags: python, design-patterns

I want to print the below pattern

```
* 
* *
* * *
* * * *
* * * * *
```

**My logic written**

```
for row in range(1,6):
  for col in range(1,6):
    if row is col:
      print(row * '* ')
```

Can someone review the code and suggest any improvements needed

The code which i have written is it a right approach ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome to Code Review.

Your code is literally 4 lines. So there isn't much to review.

- Do not use the `is` operator to compare the integers. See [difference between `is` and `==`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is)
- You can save the nested loop: you are already ensuring `col == row` so you can instead write:

```py
for row in range(1,6):
    print("* " * row)
```

- If we want to get technical, the code you have written has a time complexity of **O(n^3)**, but the problem can be solved in **O(n^2)**. You can read more on this topic [here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.mygreatlearning.com/blog/why-is-time-complexity-essential/%3famp).